# Sorting in outlook by flag - change sort order

Tags: microsoft-outlook, sorting

I would like to make outlook to sort my messages in a certain search folder by the following order:

First - sort by flag status in the following order: followup flag first, unflagged second, completed last.
The secondary sort is by date.

That is - I want to see flagged items first even if they are not very recent. I still want to see the completed items in the search folder but they should be according to the date and not placed on the top.

I can make this sort happen except for the flag sort order. Outlook sort my flags as follows: folloup first, completed second and unFlagged last. How can I make it sort only by flagged (without completed) and all the rest? Other solution to my problem?

Thanks,
Roee

Answer (score 0):

According to my test, I'm afraid that we could not sort items sort by flag status in the order of followup flag first, unflagged second, completed last. As I know, completed is also a status of flag and its priority should be higher than the unflagged items which is by design and we could not make changes to it.